# UK Post Code returns all possible addresses

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api

On a website 
https://bookings.royalmailsameday.com/acinet.dll/quote
I saw a feature.
Give a postcode to input field of Postcode, and click a button "Lookup Address".{test postcode value:CR0 3RL}
Then a list of addresses is populated  in a box.
Please tell me how these website guys doing it,as I tried to find by console,but no AJAX call is going out.

```
On a website 
https://bookings.royalmailsameday.com/acinet.dll/quote
I saw a feature,
Give a postcode to input field of Postcode, and click a button "Lookup Address".

Then a list of addresses is populated as dropdown in input field.
Please tell me how these website guys doing it,
as I tried to find by console,but no ajax call is going out.
```

Comment: Not sure they use AJAX calls. Looks more like they're Calling some internal method in the code behind to do the lookup. If so, there's probably not anything open for you to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using an hidden iframe at the bottom of the page:

```
<iframe src="https://bookings.royalmailsameday.com/acinet.dll/address_lookup?addressno=XXXXX&postcode=XXXX&nocache=XXXX" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

They assign the query url to the iframe and than inspect the response.

Nothing fancy nor extremely efficient, in my opinion.

Comment: Thankyou @Federico Dipuma,,,can I use that ifram in my website?